# Using Append and last modified in sqoop import statement

Tags: hdfs, bigdata, sqoop

We are using `sqoop` to extract data from Oracle database to `HDFS`. People used to update and add new rows regularly to the SQL table. I am aware of `sqoop` incremental imports `--append` and `--last modified` options.

My question is whether we can use both options in same import statement?

For example,

```
sqoop --incremental import --lastmodified --append --check-column 'lastmodified' --check-column 'id' --lastvalue '2017-09-22-123456' --lastvalue 100
```

Or we need to use separately? Or any other better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

`lastmodified`  can take care of both updates and newly added rows based on the last modified column. No need of using `Append` in this scenario.